# F-key keymapping in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm unable to get certain F keys to work setting up custom key mappings in Android Studio. F5, F6, F8, F10 work for example, but not F7 or F9.

It's not even telling me there are conflicts with F7 or F9, it just doesn't even register that the key was pressed when doing the mapping.  Can't I use F9 for mapping to "Make Project"?

I did change to the Eclipse keymap settings first thing, so I'm trying to further edit "Eclipse copy".

Answer (score 4):

If you use Mac, make sure that the checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. key as standard function keys" is checked. It worked for me. Go to `System Preferences > Keyboard` to find the checkbox.
[image: Use F1, F2, etc. key as standard function keys]

> OS: macOS Sierra, 10.12.4 (16E195)
>
> Android Studio: 2.3.1

Comment: Linux, no Mac. Ah well, I can't even remember if I figured it out. lol !